# sql server 2008, COUNT and DISTINCT combine together

Tags: sql-server

This is my code. it is total 109 rows.

1.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(SELECT top 1 lastname+', '+firstname FROM users WHERE privilege not in 
('Counselor','Guardian') AND userindex IN (SELECT userindex FROM studenttouser 
WHERE studentindex = students.studentindex)) AS teacher
```

this code gives me 9 rows of teacher's names.

2.

```
SELECT COUNT(students.lastname) as total_student
from table
where (SELECT top 1 lastname+', '+firstname FROM users WHERE privilege not in 
('Counselor','Guardian') AND userindex IN (SELECT userindex FROM studenttouser 
WHERE studentindex = students.studentindex))='sam'
```

this code gives me

```
column1
  34
```

the question is how to combine together.  COUNT students.name-column1, DISTINCT teacher-column2

I only need list of names and total. for example;

```
name     total_student
sam          24
John         35
Julie        34
```

and so on....
I am having a trouble with the counting students. it is ok just by itself, but when I use the DISTINCT and COUNT it gives me an error.

I tried

```
SELECT COUNT(students.lastname) as Student_total, 
DISTINCT(SELECT top 1 lastname+', '+firstname FROM users 
WHERE privilege not in 
('Counselor','Guardian') AND userindex IN (SELECT userindex FROM studenttouser 
WHERE studentindex = students.studentindex)) AS teacher
```

doesn't work. HELP!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Join` and `Group By`.
I cant be sure of unless knowing your Table structures and DB Design as this Table seems slightly complicated as it requires a self join.
You can try something on these lines.

```
SELECT Name, total_student

FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT(SELECT top 1 lastname+', '+firstname as Name
FROM users WHERE privilege not in 
   ('Counselor','Guardian') AND userindex IN (SELECT userindex FROM studenttouser 
   WHERE studentindex = students.studentindex))
) teacher

INNER JOIN
(
SELECT COUNT(students.lastname) as total_student
from table 
) as Student 
ON (SELECT top 1 lastname+', '+firstname 
FROM users 
WHERE privilege not in ('Counselor','Guardian') AND userindex IN (SELECT userindex FROM studenttouser 
WHERE studentindex = students.studentindex)
   )=teacher.Name

GROUP BY teacher.Name
```